# OpenGL - Position camera with 6 DOF vector

Tags: opengl

I work with an Augmented Reality framework on Android, and it gives me the camera position as a 6 degrees of freedom vector that includes the estimated camera optical and camera orientation.

Since I'm a complete newbie in OpenGL, I don't quite understand what that means and my question is - how to use this 4x4 matrix to position my camera in OpenGL.

Below is a sample from Android SDK which renders a simple textured triangle (I didn't know which details are important so I included the whole two classes - the renderer and the triangle object).

My guess is that it positions the camera with gluLookAt in onDrawFrame(). I want to adjust this,
I receive these matrices from the framework (these are just samples) -

When the camera should look directly at the triangle, I need to use a matrix of this type to somehow position my camera:

```
 0.9930384    0.045179322   0.10878302   0.0
-0.018241059  0.9713616    -0.23690554   0.0 
-0.11637083   0.23327199    0.9654233    0.0 
 21.803288   -14.920643    -150.6514     1.0
```

When I move the camera a bit far away:

```
 0.9763242    0.041258257   0.21234424   0.0 
 0.014808476  0.96659267   -0.2558918    0.0 
-0.21580763   0.25297752    0.94309634   0.0 
 17.665      -18.520836    -243.28784    1.0
```

When I tilt my camera a bit to the right:

```
 0.8340566    0.0874321     0.5447095    0.0 
 0.054606464  0.96943074   -0.23921578   0.0 
-0.5489726    0.22926341    0.8037848    0.0 
-8.809776    -7.5869675    -244.01971    1.0
```

Any thoughts? My guess is that the only thing that matters is actually the last row, everything else is close to zero.

I'd be happy to get any advice on how to adjust this code to use those matrices, including any settings such as setting perspective matrices or whatsoever (again, a newbie).

```
public class TriangleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

public TriangleRenderer(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mTriangle = new Triangle();
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    /*
     * By default, OpenGL enables features that improve quality
     * but reduce performance. One might want to tweak that
     * especially on software renderer.
     */
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);

    /*
     * Some one-time OpenGL initialization can be made here
     * probably based on features of this particular context
     */
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
            GL10.GL_FASTEST);

    gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /*
     * Create our texture. This has to be done each time the
     * surface is created.
     */

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

    mTextureID = textures[0];
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
            GL10.GL_REPLACE);

    InputStream is = mContext.getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.raw.robot);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    /*
     * By default, OpenGL enables features that improve quality
     * but reduce performance. One might want to tweak that
     * especially on software renderer.
     */
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);

    gl.glTexEnvx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
            GL10.GL_MODULATE);

    /*
     * Usually, the first thing one might want to do is to clear
     * the screen. The most efficient way of doing this is to use
     * glClear().
     */

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*
     * Now we're ready to draw some 3D objects
     */

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
    float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);

    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

    mTriangle.draw(gl);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    /*
    * Set our projection matrix. This doesn't have to be done
    * each time we draw, but usually a new projection needs to
    * be set when the viewport is resized.
    */

    float ratio = (float) w / h;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

}

private Context mContext;
private Triangle mTriangle;
private int mTextureID;} class Triangle {
public Triangle() {

    // Buffers to be passed to gl*Pointer() functions
    // must be direct, i.e., they must be placed on the
    // native heap where the garbage collector cannot
    // move them.
    //
    // Buffers with multi-byte datatypes (e.g., short, int, float)
    // must have their byte order set to native order

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTS * 3 * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTS * 2 * 4);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTexBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();

    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTS * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mIndexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();

    // A unit-sided equalateral triangle centered on the origin.
    float[] coords = {
            // X, Y, Z
            -0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.0f,  0.559016994f, 0
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < VERTS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            mFVertexBuffer.put(coords[i*3+j] * 2.0f);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VERTS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            mTexBuffer.put(coords[i*3+j] * 2.0f + 0.5f);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < VERTS; i++) {
        mIndexBuffer.put((short) i);
    }

    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
    mTexBuffer.position(0);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, VERTS,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);
}

private final static int VERTS = 3;

private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
private FloatBuffer mTexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer mIndexBuffer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trick" is to understand, that OpenGL does not have a camera. What is does is transforming the whole world by a movement that's the exact opposite of what a camera would have to be moved from position (0,0,0).

Such transformations (=movements) are described in form of so called *homogenous transformation matrices*. Fixed Function OpenGL uses a combination of two matrices:

- Modelview **M**, which describes placement of the world and view (and objects within the world to some degree).
- Projection **P**, which could be seen as kind of "lens" of the virtual camera (remember, there is no camera in OpenGL).

Any vertex position **v** is transformed by **c = P * M * v** (**c** is the transformed vertex coordinate in clip space, that is screen space not in pixels but with the screen edges at -1, 1 – the viewport then maps from clip space to screen pixel space).

What Android gives you is such a transformation matrix. I'm not sure, but looking at the values it might be, that you're given **P * M**. As long as there is no lighting involved you can load that directly into the modelview matrix using `glLoadMatrix`, and projection being set to identity. You pass matrices to OpenGL as a array of 16 floats; the indexing order of OpenGL sometimes confuses people, but the way you dumped the android matrices I think you already got them right (you printed them "wrong", transposed that is, which is the same pitfall people fall into with OpenGL glLoadMatrix, but two times transposing is identity, it's probably right. If it doesn't work at first, flip column and rows, i.e. "mirror" the matrix on its diagonal running from up-left do bottom-right).